# Estimating transformation of checker board points in Matlab or openCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d

I have 2 sets of checker board images,18 images in one set. Set1 is for camera1 and Set2 is for camera2. Each image has 54 control points((x,y). I want to estimate the transformation matrix from camera1 to camera2 using this data.

I know that estimateGeometricTransform() functions exists in matlab but this is only for one image, I have 18 images.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d/py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html) is a link to some *very* useful documentation/tutorials on 3D calibration/pose estimation/getting a depth map from stereo vision for OpenCV in Python. (porting it to C++ will not be difficult as they use the same functions)

Follow through all four sections and I'm willing to bet you will find a solution.

Good luck, Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `estimateCameraParameters` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox, or using the [Stereo Camera Calibrator App](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-camera-calibrator-app.html).